# How can I make the get_random_string Django module to return only numerical values?

Tags: python, django, random

What should I do to my simple code below, so that it only returns numerical values?

```
>>> from django.utils.crypto import get_random_string
>>> get_random_string(10)
>>> 'PhaWT9X02U'
```

Something like: `1067603657`
And if it is possible, can you recommend an id field generated in this manner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `allowed_chars`

```
get_random_string(10, allowed_chars='0123456789')
```

And to use as id:

```
def random_id():
   random_str = get_random_string(10, allowed_chars='0123456789')
   return int(random_str)
```

And add id field to your model like that:

```
id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, default=random_id, editable=False)
```

Comment: Thanks alot @Reza Heydari, so can you recommend this method as a way of generating an id with primary_key=True, guaranteeing a very very small probability of returning a duplicate?

Comment: There is no guarantee that function doesn't return a duplicate but I think django try to add unique value for id.

Answer (score 0):

We can extend Reeza's solution by adding a uniqueness constraint to to the field to enable unique behaviour of the ID and by making the generator function aware of database state.

```
def random_id():    
   random_int = int(get_random_string(10, allowed_chars='0123456789'))
   while YourModel.objects.filter(id=random_int).exists():       
      random_int = int(get_random_string(10, allowed_chars='0123456789'))    
   return random_int
```

and then

```
id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, default=random_id, editable=False, unique=True)
```

The performance trade-off is minimal for most cases as chances of a collision is minimal and so this function will not be run more than once (there are 10^10 possibilities for this ID).